# Draw (extend) a straight line from points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, clip

Is there any existent tool or workflow to generate a straight line in ArcMap?
I have a lot of point that represent plant counting (one point per plant) and I need to generate e line that represents the row lines of the crop. The points are not generated in the same order of the line, and there is no field in the attribute table to use as a reference to draw a line. 
Our ideia is to draw the first segment of each line and try to use some tool that test all the closest points and then draw the next segment based on the angle variation of the two segments (The closest to 0 is the best choice).

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you identify the first and last point for each line?  Since you're already suggesting to use the first two points, can you instead use the first and last points?  If so, you may then be able to select all the points that are within a distance of that line (select by location), and then use the Points to Line tool for those points, sorting the points based on the X and/or Y coordinates (you can add these as fields using Add Geometry Attributes tool).

Comment: If space between plants on a same row significantly smaller than distance between rows try minimum spanning tree. You can split result at vertices, delete longer segments and dissolve again.

Comment: The distance between the next point in the row and the point of the next row is not very different. Searching for the minimum distance is not a good idea. Considering I have a lot of rows side by side, I can't use the point to line tool based on the X or Y coordinates. What I want to do is the same thing as this software does, but for free :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwIDbXHS8nY#t=60